# Overtaking on the autobahn - time, distance, and Vmax?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Assume you're driving your dream sports car of length (l). You're on the autobahn, stuck behind a 60-foot long tractor trailer traveling at a constant 50mph (i.e., both vehicles start at Vo = 50mph). When the traffic clears and you pull over to the passing lane, if you accelerate at your maximum acceleration (a), then:

1. How long (time) will it take to reach three of your car lengths ahead of the tractor trailer to safely pass it?
2. What distance will you have traveled once you reach the safe passing distance of 3l in front of the tractor trailer, and
3. What is your velocity once you have achieved the necessary safe passing distance?

Assume your car's acceleration (a) is constant.

Comment: If you are on the Autobahn, you really should be measuring speeds and distances in metric.

Comment: well said @DougM

Comment: Units are irrelevant as long as they're consistent, but true - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac 12 at^2  = 60 + 3l\\
t = \sqrt {\frac {120 + 6l}{a}}\\
v = 50 + at \\
x = 50t + \frac 12 at^2$

Comment: The first equation is true in the relative frame of the truck you're passing only, correct?  It's not true in the relative frame of the road.  The truck is moving at 50mph, so that every second it travels 73.33 feet or ~22.35 meters. So your distance d=1/2at^2 must take this motion into account, no?

Comment: So thinking about this more - my sports car is accelerating from "zero" in the truck's relative frame since the difference between speeds at the start is zero (both traveling at 50mph or 80.46kph or 134,440 furlongs/fortnight).

Comment: So, the distance I must travel is actually the length of the truck (60ft, 18.28m, whatever) plus 3 of my car lengths, *plus* the distance the truck travels in the time it takes for me to accelerate past it and travel the three extra car lengths.  So, I think the first equation should be 1/2at^2=60+3l+73.33t (Assuming units are feet per second) ?

Comment: Yes to find the time it takes for your car to pass, it is simpler to look at the problem from the frame of reference of the truck.  To find the total distance covered, $50 t$ is the distance the truck covers in time $t.$  $\frac 12 at^2 = 60 + 3l$.  Giving the $x = 50 t + \frac 12 at^2$ above.